# PropertyIsEqualTo And PropertyIsLike filter

Tags: geoserver, sld, xml

I'm trying to label points with a rule based on two fields:

1. Text
2. kkod

I need to create a rule: "When the letter E is in Text field and kkod=79" then label with the Text field content.

So the first point should be labeled "E4" but not the second:
[image]

This give "No validation errors." but makes all other labels not show. What is the problem?

```
<Rule>
 <Name>Europavag</Name>
 <ogc:Filter>
 <ogc:And>
  
   <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
     <ogc:PropertyName>kkod</ogc:PropertyName>
     <ogc:Literal>79</ogc:Literal>
   </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
  
  <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="." escape="!">
    <ogc:PropertyName>kkod</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>*E*</ogc:Literal>
   </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
  
  </ogc:And>
 </ogc:Filter>
 
  <PointSymbolizer>
    <Graphic>
      <Mark>
        <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#0033cc</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </Mark>
      <Size>1</Size>
    </Graphic>
  </PointSymbolizer>
  <TextSymbolizer>
  <Label>
    <ogc:PropertyName>text</ogc:PropertyName>
  </Label>
  <Font>
    <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
    <CssParameter name="font-size">16</CssParameter>
    <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
    <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
  </Font>
    </PointPlacement>
  </LabelPlacement>
  <Fill>
    <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
  </Fill>
</TextSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your label will show when (and only when) `kkod` is `79` **and** `kkod` contains an `E`, so never. I'd make the 2nd property reference `text`.